# Has behaviour of upstart changed in 13.04

Tags: 13.04, startup, upstart

I have an upstart conf that mounts a remote nfs at startup. Previously (in 12.10) it used

`start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)`

in 13.04 this no longer works - I tried all variants you can think of eg, runlevels, IFACE=!lo etc.

To get it to work on 13.04, I changed back to the original `start on`, but used a script with a `sleep 10` before the mount - this worked.

Has something changed in 13.04 that affects this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it should be 'IFACE!=lo' and not 'IFACE=!lo', but I'll assume this is a typo in your question.

That said, I'm having the exact same problem, and even tried different machines running 13.04 and the problem was reproduced. But from what I have gathered, no, nothing changed in Upstart 1.8.

I find that while 'net-device-up IFACE=***' does not work at all in the complex upstart job I wrote, it will work if I put it in simple job such as:

```
# /etc/init/debug.conf
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE!=lo)
script
  exec 1>>/tmp/log.file
  echo "$0:$$:`date`: got called. Environment of job $JOB was:"
  env
  echo
end script
```

So, clearly there's something else going on here. I'm reading the /var/log/syslog and /var/log/kern.log logs but couldn't pick up a candidate for culprit yet.

My solution (to the other, complex job) was to leave out the interface and just write:

```
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up)
```

This worked perfectly. However this is not good enough for me yet, since my script will be run on machines with multiple interfaces. I'll update this answer if I find a better solution than my workaround or yours.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate way to mount a remote NFS at start up is to put it in `/etc/fstab`.

```
server:/export /mount/point nfs nobootwait,nfsvers=4
```

This line will mount '/export' from 'server' at boot time, but it will not hold up the boot process. *Every* time a network device comes up, if not mounted `mountall` will attempt to mount it again.